# How can you do a non-case sensitive search of an array?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function that returned a list of unique names in a spreadsheet column.  I was looking for a way that I could make the check not case sensitive without forcing everything lowercase.   Here is my original code:

```
function testGetUniqueClassNames(){
   var sheet =  getRosterSheet();
   var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
   var indices = returnIndices();
   dataRange = dataRange.getValues();
   var classNames = getUniqueClassNames(dataRange, indices.clsNameIndex, indices.crfIdIndex);

   Logger.log(classNames);
}


function getUniqueClassNames(dataRange, clsNameIndex, crfIdIndex) {
  var classNames = [];
  for (var i=2; i<dataRange.length; i++) {
    var thisClassName = dataRange[i][clsNameIndex];
    var thisClassRoot = dataRange[i][crfIdIndex]; 

 if ((classNames.indexOf(thisClassName)==-1)&&(thisClassName!='')&&(thisClassRoot!='')) {
      classNames.push(thisClassName);
    }

  }
  classNames.sort();
  return classNames;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I created a second lowercase array to check against, but used the original one in the return.

```
function testGetUniqueClassNames(){
   var sheet =  getRosterSheet();
   var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
   var indices = returnIndices();
   dataRange = dataRange.getValues();
   var classNames = getUniqueClassNames(dataRange, indices.clsNameIndex, indices.crfIdIndex);

   Logger.log(classNames);
}


function getUniqueClassNames(dataRange, clsNameIndex, crfIdIndex) {
  var classNames = [];
  var classNamesLC = [];
  for (var i=2; i<dataRange.length; i++) {
    var thisClassName = dataRange[i][clsNameIndex];
    var thisClassNameLC = thisClassName.toLowerCase();
    var thisClassRoot = dataRange[i][crfIdIndex];

 if ((classNamesLC.indexOf(thisClassNameLC)==-1)&&(thisClassName!='')&&(thisClassRoot!='')) {
      classNames.push(thisClassName);
      classNamesLC.push(thisClassNameLC);       
    }  


  }
  classNames.sort();
  return classNames;

}
```

Comment: Nice simple answer and straight to the point. Exactly what I would have said.

Nice one :)